# Geocoder is undefined?

Tags: android, location

> I'm trying to get user location using GPS, but i need to convert the lat and long to address but Geocoder keep giving a error gc is undefined.

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{

            public void onLocationChanged(Location loc){

                try{
                Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);
                List <Address> addr = gc.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(),loc.getLongitude(),1);
                if (addr != null && addr.size() > 0){
                    Address address = addr.get(0);
                    String results = address.getAddressLine(0);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),results,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                }catch(Exception e){

                }

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your imports have this

```
import android.location.Geocoder;
```

And also,

this refer to your locationlistener class. So put your activityname.this instead of this

```
Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(youractivityname.this, Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: hi, already import, is there any errors in the following code?

Comment: Use Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(yourActivityname.this, Locale.ENGLISH);

Comment: Hi again, will the results i declared return a address name or street name?

Comment: i think it return street name

Comment: get detailed address by addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
         addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();,etc..